# Image not load Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, controller, load

I have a problem trying to load an image from a controller to another. The problem is that when trying to load the new Controller runs 2 times the same class.

Code in ViewController

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        let row = ids[indexPath.row]
        let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewsController") as! NewsController
        next.id = row
        self.presentViewController(next, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
```

And code in NewsController:

```
  func tableView(tableView:   UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            // Retrieve cell

            let cellIdentifier: String = "NewCell"
            let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as!NewDetailCell

            // Get the location to be shown
            let item: LocationModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! LocationModel


            myCell.titLabel!.text  =   item.titulo
            myCell.subLabel!.text   =  item.subtitulo
            myCell.cuerpoLabel!.text = item.cuerpo
            var urlimg : String = item.imgNot!

            if urlimg == ""{
                urlimg = "abc.jpg"
            }
            var image = UIImageView()

            image = loadImageFromUrl("MyURL" + urlimg, view: myCell.newImage!)!
myCell.newImage = image
    .
    .
    .
```

loadImageFromUrl():

```
func loadImageFromUrl(url: String!, view: UIImageView!) -> UIImageView?{

        // Create Url from string
        let url = NSURL(string: url)!

        // Download task:
        // - sharedSession = global NSURLCache, NSHTTPCookieStorage and NSURLCredentialStorage objects.
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (responseData, responseUrl, error) -> Void in
            // if responseData is not null...
            if let data = responseData{

                // execute in UI thread
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    view.image = UIImage(data: data)
                })

            }
        }

        // Run task
        task.resume()
        return UIImageView (image : view.image)
    }
```

THANKS!

Comment: What are you saying? You say "The problem is that when trying to load the new Controller runs 2 times the same class." What does that mean? You show your source view controller setting a property `id` in the destination view controller using the selected row, but then you never show that id property being used. What do you want to happen, and what is happening instead?

Comment: The problem is that when invoking New Controller, this runs 2 times, I do not know why.

Comment: **WHAT** runs 2 times? And why do you conclude that something is running 2 times?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your URL string that you pass in loadImageFromUrl.
Also i think it's better to get as a parameter only URlString and return a completionBlockWith UIImage?

Comment: ImageView is object from UITableViewCell, you should to manage loading image inside UItableViewCell, all you need is to pass LocationModel in your cell and there configure as you want all elements.